# Why can't I hear sound on pygame mixer?

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

Whenever I run this code, I can't hear the sound play and I even check to see if it plays then go on to the next line but it goes on to the next line and no noise comes out. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import time
import sys


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

binaryHighLow = "010111"


def check():
    for x in binaryHighLow:
        if x == "0" in binaryHighLow:
            lowPitch = pygame.mixer.Sound("440Hz_44100Hz_16bit_05sec.wav")
            lowPitch.play()
            print("Low")
            lowPitch.set_volume(1)
            time.sleep(lowPitch.get_length())
        elif x == "1" in binaryHighLow:
            highPitch = pygame.mixer.Sound("5000hz.wav")
            highPitch.play()
            print("High")
            highPitch.set_volume(1)
            time.sleep(highPitch.get_length())



check()
```

Any suggestions for what I should change to the code?

Comment: Try putting the `pygame.init()` after the `pygame.mixer.init()`

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `pygame.init()` after the `pygame.mixer.init()`.

e.g.:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()
```

Comment: Since `pygame.init()` will call `init()` on all modules, there's no point in calling `pygame.mixer.init()` (without parameters) and `pygame.init()`.